# Read and resize png files matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 10 images all named ax1.png .. ax2.png all the way to ax10.png

I am aiming to read them all in and resize them.

I have tried the following:

```
fileFolder = 'mrivolumeimages';
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'ax%d.png'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name};

for k=1:length(fileNames)
    H=fileNames{k};
    S=imread(H);
    I=imresize(S, [690 896]);
    [SUCCESS,MESSAGE,MESSAGEID] = mkdir('mrivolumeimages','New_folder');
    imwrite(I,fullfile('New_folder',H));
end
```

But it does not seem to work. I want to create the new resized images and save them within my directory. could I please have some advice on why this would not work?

Comment: What does not work? Any error message?

Comment: @Daniel no there is no error message. I just do not get a directory and do not get the resized images

Comment: Do you have write permissions in folder `mrivolumeimages`?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes looking in Finder i have read and write permissions. but i still get the error for unable to write the new image there?

Comment: @Ph9 please accept the helpful answer, provide additional useful information as a **comment** to that answer, **but do not change your question**. SO also aims to help future users in similar situations who will be unable to understand the question-answer-*pair* if the question was edited after the answer was given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fileFolder = '/Users/PJ/Documents/MATLAB/ToolboxLS-1.1.1/Dissertation/mrivolumeimages';
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'ax*.png'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name};

for k=1:length(fileNames)
  H=fileNames{k};
  S=imread(H);
  I=imresize(S, [896 690]);
  [SUCCESS,MESSAGE,MESSAGEID] = mkdir('ResizedAx');
  imwrite(I,fullfile('ResizedAx',H));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use wildchars (`'*'`) in `dir`  and not string format chars (`'%d'`):

```
dirOutput = dir(fullfile(fileFolder,'ax*.png'));
```

Alternatively, you can specify the number using

```
for k=1:10
    H = fullfile( fileFolder, sprintf( 'ax%d.png', k )  );
    % and you can continue from here...
end
```

Comment: thanks! i am now getting an error saying it cannot write to the folder?